# How do I point my web application from port number 8080 to 80?

Tags: apache, tomcat, jakarta-ee, tomcat7, windows-server-2008

I know this seems like a very basic question.

I have a Java EE web application running on port 8080. So when I try to access it, I have to type `domainname.com:8080/DomainName` . I want to access it by `domainname.com` . For which I'm supposed to change the port number from `8080` to `80`. I made this change in my `server.xml` in the `conf` folder after going thru a few answers on SO :

`<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />`

But I still get a 404 error. Please help. Is there something I'm not doing/doing wrong?

I'm using Tomcat7 on a Windows server.

If there's a similar question (which I may have not come across) please post it in the comments, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can install apache and configure it to work with your tomcat via AJP port so apache will listen on port 80 and redirect request to your tomcat

here some reference:
http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/ApachePlusTomcat_HowTo.html

Comment: Hi Evgeny! I was following the tutorial - I just couldn't find the httpd.conf file! I'm really quite stuck! Isn't there any other way I can make it run on port 80?

Comment: Did you install Apache HTTP Server?
You can download it here
https://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi#apache24
the httpd.conf file is in the conf direttory

Comment: Actually you can use your connector as you mentioned. Did you try to get to url domainname.com/DomainName after setting port 80 in your server.xml?

Comment: There was just a httpd TXT file in that directory. I stopped the Apache2 service and restarted Tomcat and weirdly enough, I'm able to point to port 80 now :)

Comment: Well done, so you can mark my answer as correct.
thanks